# USB-C device detected only through a hub

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, usb

I am using a Presonus AudioBox 1818vsl for live performances with my band. This device has a USB-B port and it's powered through a dedicated power adapter: I connect it to my MacBook Pro with a USB-B -> USB-C cable I recently bought on Amazon (UGreen brand). Here the strange thing happens:

- If I connect the USB-C plug directly into my MacBook, the device is **not** recognized (nothing is seen on system report, just like nothing is plugged in)
- If I connect the USB-C plug into a USB hub, the device is properly recognized

If you are wondering why I need to connect the AudioBox directly to the MacBook, is due to a latency I noticed with my live instruments and microphone over the playback tracks. I've read that, sometimes, hubs introduce latency against the input signals.

By the way, I tried to connect the AudioBox directly to my home studio workstation that has a USB-C port, and it connects as I expect. Do you have any clue why this thing happens on the MacBook?

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like the adapter/cable (USB-B > USB-C) is the problem. You have shown that every other thing in the hardware chain works fine. Try an Apple USB-B > USB-C adapter. I never have problems with those.

Comment: Might be useful if you could provide the make and model of the hub.

Comment: @SteveChambers is it possible that the reason is the cable? It works on every other device if plugged directly except the MacBook Pro. Seems not much reasonable

Comment: @DavidAnderson the hub is [this one](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B09QKQ2ZYQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) a Quuge ‎S-5002W91

Comment: The cable is the cheapest and easiest "fix." If that doesn't change the behavior then you look elsewhere. First rule of troubleshooting, "*isolate and identify*" Meaning work up the chain of devices by replacing the easiest thing to replace first, then repeat with the next cheapest/easiest item to replace. Also unplug everything that is not **needed** for troubleshooting. That would be the *isolate* part...

Answer (score 0):

While a a USB 3.2 or 4 port is backward compatible all the way to USB 1.0, the quality of the USB controller

If you issue the command:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep -i hub
```

You will see a number of USB hubs, 2.0, USB3 and where applicable USB 4. even though you don’t have have that many. This is from the USB *controller chip* built into your Mac and how it achieves backward compatibility.

> - If I connect the USB-C plug directly into my MacBook [UGreen Adapter] , the device is not recognized (nothing is seen on system report, just like nothing is plugged in)
> - If I connect the USB-C plug into a USB hub, the device is properly recognize

It is likely because the UGreen adapter is of poor quality.  I have used [Anker USB-C to USB 3.0  adapters](http://radnex.us/Anker_USB-C_to_30_adapter) with a lot of success.  Just use any USB 2.0 cable between it and your Presonus (which is USB 2.0 per the [tech specs](https://legacy.presonus.com/products/AudioBox-1818VSL/tech-specs)).

#### Latency

You are correct about latency, and again this is due to the quality of the USB controller chip.  “Cheaper” hubs will use more budge chips, thus higher latency.  To avoid that get a quality hub…again I recommend [Anker](http://radnex.us/anker-usbc-hub-hdmi-4K-power-delivery)

Comment: I've tried with a Syntech USB-C to USB-A Adapter as far as the Anker was not available here in Italy. Same thing happens, nothing is seen if connected directly to my Macbook. I've tried all the 3 available ports. The adaptor is working, as if I plug it into the hub, it is seen correctly (same for my home studio workstation). Don't really know how to solve this... Spending 3k for a laptop that is giving such issue is a shame

Comment: For more clarity, I'll share the adapter I've bought [Syntech USB-C to USB-A Adapter](https://www.amazon.it/dp/B0CNK3YK1J?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details)

Comment: When using the adapter, you must also be changing the cable. I ask because the UGreen cable has a USB-C plug and the adaptor has a USB-A jack.